# How to link a HTML link with a PHP function?

Tags: php

How to link a HTML link like this - `<a href="#">Click here to log out</a>`

to a PHP function like - `logout()`

What I need to do is, when people click a link, php will run the php function.

Please advice! :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What I need to do is, when people
>   click a link, php will run the php
>   function.

You can not call a ***PHP*** (server-side language) function when clicking on a link. From your question, I suspect you want to provide a link for users to logout, below is how you should go about.

Your link should be like:

```
<a href="logout.php">Click here to log out</a>
```

And in `logout.php` you should put php code for logging the user out.

Code inside `logout.php` might look like this:

```
<?php
  session_start();
  unset($_SESSION['user']); // remove individual session var
  session_destroy();
  header('location: login.php'); // redirct to certain page now
?>
```

Comment: @Sarfarz - I'm trying to build a simple login system. So I follow this tutorial - http://tinsology.net/2009/06/creating-a-secure-login-system-the-right-way/

This is what I achieve so far - http://cokicoki.com/box/loginsys/reg.php

Please advice me if you see something weird. Thanks!

Comment: @Zhaf: It seems to be fine, however when creating such login system, you need to be aware about sql injection attacks, see more info about here: http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways; just to get this out of the way first. There is no way to invoke a PHP function from the client side (i.e, user interaction at the browser) without a page refresh unless you use AJAX. As one answer suggests, you can put the function in a PHP page, and link to it. Here's another way

```
<a href="index.php?action=logout">Logout</a>
```

And inside index.php

```
<?php
    switch $_GET['action']:
    {
         ....

         case 'logout': logout(); break;
         ...

    }
 ?>
```

There are other more sophisicated methods, such as determining which function to call from URI directly, which is used by frameworks like CodeIgniter and Kohana.